Python C extensions - Can't put float into array
I'm learning C and trying to write an extension to convert COO sparse data to a dense array.  (I know SciPy can do it.) But I'm stuck.  I can declare the integers for the 2D pointer into the array, but I can't get the float value that I want to put into the array.  I don't understand what the difference is between my PyLong_AsLong declarations that work, and my PyFloat_AsDouble that doesn't.
motion_tools.c:20:68: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'PyFloat_AsDouble'
   20 |                 double v = (double) PyFloat_AsDouble(val_float_list[i]);
      |                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
      |                                                                    |
      |                                                                    PyObject {aka struct _object}
In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:87,
                 from motion_tools.c:2:
/usr/include/python3.10/floatobject.h:49:37: note: expected 'PyObject *' {aka 'struct _object *'} but argument is of type 'PyObject' {aka 'struct _object'}
   49 | PyAPI_FUNC(double) PyFloat_AsDouble(PyObject *);
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~

# tool_test.py
import motion_tools

motion_tools.sparse_to_dense([0,1],[0,1],[1.0,1.0],(2,2))

// motion_tools.c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

PyObject *sparse2dense(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    PyObject* x_int_list; // incoming python list
    PyObject* y_int_list; // incoming python list
    PyObject* val_float_list; // incoming python list
    PyObject* shape_int_tuple; // incoming python list

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OOOO", &x_int_list, &y_int_list, &val_float_list, &shape_int_tuple))
        return NULL;

    PyObject *out_array = PyArray_Zeros(2, shape_int_tuple);
    Py_ssize_t element_count = PyList_Size(x_int_list);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<element_count; ++i){
        int x = (int) PyLong_AsLong(x_int_list[i]);  // This works
        int y = (int) PyLong_AsLong(y_int_list[i]);  // This works
        double v = (double) PyFloat_AsDouble(val_float_list[i]);  // This doesn't work.

        //out_array[y][x] = v;
        PyArray_SETITEM(out_array, PyArray_GETPTR2(out_array, y, x), v);

    }

    return PyArray_Return(out_array);
}

static PyModuleDef methods[] = {
    { "sparse_to_dense", sparse2dense, METH_VARARGS, "Converts from COO to dense array"},
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

static struct PyModuleDef sparse_to_dense = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "motion_tools",
    "Sparse to Dense module",
    -1,
    methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_motion_tools(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&sparse_to_dense);
}
'''


You pass a PyObject structure object, but the function expects a pointer to a PyObject structure object. This is quite clearly written in the error message.

I suggest learning the basics of C by itself before trying to drag in Python integration. Then you'd understand the error message (and hopefully understand C types and the Python C API documentation well enough to have not made the mistake in the first place)

If you're sure they're lists, PyList_GetItem is how you traverse them. (Possibly PySequence_GetItem if you're not sure)

That is, Python Lists/Tuples/Sequences are not directly C arrays and you can't traverse them as if they were one.  Use the API.

@Max: That said, PySequence_Fast_ITEMS will let you get the underlying C array from a list or tuple (if you're not 100% sure it's one of those, you can convert any iterable to something appropriate with PySequence_Fast, which will return existing lists and tuples unchanged on CPython, and only make a new list/tuple if the caller provided some other iterable) and do C-style access on it if you like.
